# Python Selenium Accept Cookies no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

I am getting the following error when trying to accept cookies

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[title='Accept All']"}
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.autotrader.co.uk')

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Accept All']").click()
```

Comment: Why don't I see the _Accept Cookie_ popup?

Comment: @DebanjanB me too.